# Is this hadith about satan vomiting food when Allah's name is mentioned authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

Is this hadith authentic about Shaytan vomiting food when Allah swt name mentioned?

> [Riyad as-Salihin](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/3/5) » The Book About the Etiquette of Eating
>
> Umaiyyah bin Makhshi (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>   Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was sitting while a man was eating food. That man did not mention the Name of Allah (before commencing to eat) till only a morsel of food was left. When he raised it to his mouth, he said: "Bismillah awwalahu wa akhirahu (With the Name of Allah, in the beginning and in the end)." Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) smiled at this and said, "Satan had been eating with him but when he mentioned the Name of Allah, Satan vomited all that was in his stomach."
>
> [Abu Dawud and An-Nasa'i].

Comment: Does satan really need to eat ?

Comment: @user5751924 . Jinn are not gods. They do eat and have needs and instincts.

Answer (score 3):

The hadith in Sunan Abu Dawūd you are asking about is narrated through Mu'ammal ibn al-Fadl al-Harrāni through 'Īssa ibn Yūnus through Jābir ibn Subh through Al-Muthanna ibn Abdur-Rahmān al-Khozā'i through Umayyah ibn Makhshi. The hadith is *sahih* (authentic).

Comment: Is the reference to sunan an-Nasa-I correct and if so how is the authenticity?

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I did not check the grade of the version in Sunan an-Nasa'i since the one in Sunan Abu Dawūd is already authentic. I will add this to my list to research.

Answer (score 1):

Classified as Daeef isnad (weak) by Shaikh alAlbani (رَحِمَهُ ٱللّٰهُ تعالى‎), the narrator Al-Muthanna ibn Abdur-Rahmān al-Khozā'i is Majhool (unknown) as per ibn alMadini (رَحِمَهُ ٱللّٰهُ تعالى‎)

[image: Tahqiq Riyadh alSaleheen - alAlbanee]